# How to change the length of excerpt() method?

Tags: excerpt

I am using the_excerpt() method to display some wordings from the blog posts.

I have read the post from this link.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_length

But my situation is different.

I am displaying some wordings from the posts in two places.
In the first place I want to display 20 words and in the 2nd place I want to display 50 words.

So what will I do for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top answer to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9285/excerpts-that-dont-truncate-words) handles dynamically altering the length of your excerpt using a custom excerpt function.